# Condition when any union of subgroups is subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group  and $\{H_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ for some (not necessarily countable) indexing set $\mathcal{I}$ be a family of subgroups of $G$ **none of which contain all the others**. State and prove a general condition that will imply $\bigcup \limits_{i\in\mathcal{I}}H_i$ is a subgroup of $G$.

After thinking for a day two I ran into the following idea: What if I put the following condition: For any pairs $i,j\in \mathcal{I}$ there is $k\in \mathcal{I}$ such that $H_i\subset H_k$ and $H_j\subset H_k$. And it's quite easy to show that in this case the union of $\{H_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ is a subgroup!

But I don't know what to do with the condition "none of which contain all the others"?

Comment: It seems to me that you've come up with a good idea. I suppose the condition "none of which contains all the others" is meant to preclude you from giving that as your answer. In other words, they want a condition MORE general than assuming there is one subgroup in the collection containing the rest.

Comment: @Yanko, really I did not know that there is a duplicate here ..

Comment: @RFZ at least now you can read the answer.